# checkValidity method displays all values as invalid instead of just displaying the invalid values

Tags: java

I have a feeling my issue is somewhere in my if statements in the checkValidity method, but I can't figure out where I went wrong exactly.

Here's the data values used from the file

Sorry if the values look bunched up

DELL: Dell Inc

125  25.567 0.025   28.735  0.025

MSFT: Microsoft

34.1    -15.75  0.012   15.90   0.013

GOOG: Google

56.5    58.125  0.032   67.975  0.030

IBM: IBM Corp

87.3    8.875   0.015   7.500   0.020

DTLK: DataLink

345 23.250  0.055   25.750  0.050

CSCO: Cisco

90  14.570  1.025   16.890  1.024

INTC: Intel

89.1    78.120  0.042   99.355  0.042

BGUS: Bogus Corp

0   25.567  0.012   25.678  0.023

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.io.*;

public class Profit
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String input;                                     //string for input from opened file
        //Boolean TFStatement;                            //true/ false statement for validity
        int shares = 0;                                       //number of stocks
        String company;                                   //name of the company
        double sellPrice = 0;                                 //sell price per stock
        double buyPrice = 0;                                  //purchase price per stock
        double sellTotal = 0;                                 //selling total w/o factoring in commission amount
        double buyTotal = 0;                                  //purchase total w/o factoring in buying commission amount
        double sellCommissionPercentage = 0;                  //commission percentage for selling the stock
        double buyCommissionPercentage = 0;                   //commission percentage for buying the stock
        double profit = 0;                                    //total profit after buying and selling stocks
        double buyCommission = 0;                             //total purchase commission amount
        double sellCommission = 0;                            //total selling commission amount
        DecimalFormat formatPercent = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00%");   //format of currency for the profit

        //Scanner for keyboard input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Get file
        System.out.print("Sean Harris\n\n" + "File name: ");
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        //Open file
        File stockFile = new File(filename);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(stockFile);


        //loop until fils has no more lines to read
        while (inputFile.hasNext())
            {
                company = inputFile.nextLine();
                shares = inputFile.nextInt();
                buyPrice = inputFile.nextDouble();
                buyCommissionPercentage = inputFile.nextDouble();
                sellPrice = inputFile.nextDouble();
                sellCommissionPercentage = inputFile.nextDouble();

                if (checkValidity(company, shares, buyPrice, buyCommissionPercentage, sellPrice, sellCommissionPercentage) == (false))
                    calcProfit(shares, buyPrice, buyCommissionPercentage, sellPrice, sellCommissionPercentage, profit, buyCommission, sellCommission, sellTotal, buyTotal);
                    display(company, profit);
            }
    }

    /**
        Check if the info in the file is valid
    */
    public static boolean checkValidity(String theCompany,int theShares, double theBuyPrice, double theBuyCommissionPercentage, double theSellPrice, double theSellCommissionPercentage)
    {
        //checking all of the values to see if they are valid

        Boolean TFStatement;

        TFStatement = (theShares <= 0 || theBuyPrice < 0 || theBuyCommissionPercentage < 0 || theBuyCommissionPercentage > .20 || theSellCommissionPercentage < 0 || theSellCommissionPercentage > .20 || theSellPrice < 0 ? true : false);
        /*
        if (theShares <= 0 || theBuyPrice < 0 || theBuyCommissionPercentage < 0 || theBuyCommissionPercentage > .20 || theSellCommissionPercentage < 0 || theSellCommissionPercentage > .20 || theSellPrice < 0)
            TFStatement = true;
        else
            TFStatement = false;
        */

        //displaying the invalid message if a value is invalid
        if (theShares <= 0)
            System.out.println(theCompany);
            System.out.println("Number of shares invalid: " + theShares);

        if (theBuyPrice < 0)
            System.out.println(theCompany);
            System.out.println("Purchase price invalid: " + theBuyPrice);

        if (theBuyCommissionPercentage < 0 || theBuyCommissionPercentage > .20)
            System.out.println(theCompany);
            System.out.println("Purchase commission percent invalid: " + theBuyCommissionPercentage);

        if (theSellPrice < 0)
            System.out.println(theCompany);
            System.out.println("Sales price invalid: " + theSellPrice);

        if (theSellCommissionPercentage < 0 || theSellCommissionPercentage > .20)
            System.out.println(theCompany);
            System.out.println("Sales commission percent invalid: " +theSellCommissionPercentage);

        return TFStatement;
    }

    /**
        Calculate profit
    */
    public static double calcProfit(int theShares, double theBuyPrice, double theBuyCommissionPercentage, double theSellPrice, double theSellCommissionPercentage, double theProfit, double theBuyCommission, double theSellCommission, double theSellTotal, double theBuyTotal)
    {
        //getting the total price of shares sold and bought
        //then figure out commission
        //then use the four values to calculate profit
        theSellTotal = theSellPrice * theShares;
        theBuyTotal = theBuyPrice * theShares;
        theSellCommission = theSellTotal * theSellCommissionPercentage;
        theBuyCommission = theBuyTotal * theBuyCommissionPercentage;
        theProfit = (theSellTotal - theSellCommission) - (theBuyTotal + theBuyCommission);
        return theProfit;
    }

    /**
        Display company name and profit
    */
    public static void display(String theCompany, double theProfit)
    {
        System.out.println(theCompany);
        System.out.println(theProfit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a (short) sample data file that shows your problem?

Comment: you should use `{` and `}` to delimit the `if` statements' body

Comment: oh yeah, sorry. i'll edit it

Comment: @Titus nailed it I think. Based on your indentation, your `if` blocks end much earlier than you think. Use braces to define them.

Comment: @Titus Oh, I see now. Since there are multiple statements in the if w/o a brace, it treats the second statement in the if as independent?

Comment: Yes that is right, as @RealSkeptic mentioned in his answer, in Java indentation doesn't indicate nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example this statement:

```
    //displaying the invalid message if a value is invalid
    if (theShares <= 0)
        System.out.println(theCompany);
        System.out.println("Number of shares invalid: " + theShares);
```

Perhaps you're coming from a Python background, but in Java, indentation does not indicate nesting. It's merely a readability aid. The only statement that is inside the `if` is the statement that immediately follows it. In this case: `System.out.println(theCompany);`.

If you want more than one statement to belong to the same `if`, they have to be placed in curly braces that makes them a "compound statement":

```
    if (theShares <= 0) {
        System.out.println(theCompany);
        System.out.println("Number of shares invalid: " + theShares);
    }
```

This applies to all the similar `if` statements in your code.

---

Another, unrelated, note:

There is no point in comparing a boolean to `false`. The equivalent of

```
if ( checkValidity(...) == (false) ) ...
```

is simply:

```
if ( ! checkValidity() ) ...
```

It's not *wrong* per se, but it's less readable. Booleans can be used directly in conditions.

For the same reason, an expression like:

```
condition1 || condition2 || condition3 ? true : false
```

Is redundant. It's simply equivalent to

```
condition 1 || condition2 || condition3
```

Again - it's not wrong, just not readable. A boolean is a boolean.